# Typescript with Redux, how to use connect without re-declaring action definition?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm having some inconveniences with typescript and redux-thunk actions.

Basically my components make heavy use of react-redux connect to bind action creators, the problem is, when I create the interface for this redux actions within the component, I have to re-declare the function definition because it gets lost on the connect call.

Here is a sample code:

Action Creator

```
import api from './api';
import { Dispatch } from 'redux';
import { IReduxAction } from 'model';

export const FETCH_ENTITY = 'location/FETCH_ENTITY';
export function fetchEntity(id: string) {
  return (dispatch: Dispatch<IReduxAction>) => {
    dispatch({type: `${FETCH_ENTITY}_REQUEST`, payload: {id}});

    return api.fetchEntity(id)
              .then((res) => {

                dispatch({ type: `${FETCH_ENTITY}_DONE`, payload: res });
                return res;
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                dispatch({type: `${FETCH_ENTITY}_FAIL`, payload: err, error: true});
                throw err;
              });
  };
}
```

Component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import {
  fetchEntity,
} from 'actions';

interface IStateProps {
  startingEntities: any[];
}

interface IDispatchProps {
  fetchEntity: (id: string) => Promise<any>; // <- this is what I'm trying to get rid of, basically whenever I change the action creator I have to change this definition everytime
}

class Dashboard extends React.Component<IStateProps & IDispatchProps, void> {

  public render() {

    return (<div>...RENDER SOMETHING...</div>);
  }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state: any, ownProps: any) => {
  const startingEntities = foo(); // not important

  return {
    startingEntities,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => {
  return bindActionCreators({
    fetchEntity
  }, dispatch);
};

export default connect<IStateProps, IDispatchProps, void>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard);
```

Is there anyway to declare this binded action creator without having to re-declare it everytime on each file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to define the function type again. You can use `typeof`:

```
interface IDispatchProps {
  fetchEntity: typeof fetchEntity
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with TypeScript (mostly have just done `index.d.ts` files for library interfaces) but you should be able to get the type system to do the work for you by correctly typing `fetchEntity` and exporting it for `IDispatchProps` to use.  Something like

```
//...

import { ThunkAction } from 'redux-thunk'

//...

export interface FetchEntity {
  (id: string): ThunkAction<Promise<any>, IReduxAction, any>;
}

//...

export const fetchEntity: FetchEntity = (id: string) => {
  return (dispatch: Dispatch<IReduxAction>) => {
    //...
  };
}
```

And then you can import it and use the same definition

```
//...

import {
  fetchEntity,
  FetchEntity
} from 'actions';

//...

interface IDispatchProps {
  fetchEntity: FetchEntity
}

//...
```

Comment: I seemed to work fine, but when I tried compiling the code realized the type is not a promise, in my code I'm using a .then after the call is finished to perform some other UI action, maybe I'm using an anti pattern?

Comment: @ospfranco, I think Ninten has the better solution anyway.

Comment: Ninten response also suffers the same problem, the thunk definition is not a promise, as such I cannot call .then() on that type

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand the design pattern that you're looking for but the action creator is just a simple object with a property 'type' required for the reducer when it uses it.

Therefore I would assume that the best way to handle that is to get a dedicated file with your actions that you will export and then import them. Your logic about the selection of the action to dispatc would be in your component behaviour which seems to me better.

I hope this would help and solve your issue :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment but that is not my problem as you can see my actions are already in a separate file (import {
  fetchEntity,
} from 'actions';), I'm trying to deal with type definitions for my actions, more specifically, re-declaring the type definition everytime I use `connect` in a component.

Comment: Ok, my understanding about typescript prevent me for helping more :( sorry